# How do I perform percent increase calculations to two columns side by side?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, percentage

I want to perform a percent increase calculations between every pair of variables in the two columns in my dataframe.

Something around the sense of

```
   a  b  
0  5  10  
1  1  2  
2  3  6
```

And I'd like something like this

1 being 100% increase

```
   a  b  %  
0  5  10 1  
1  1  2  1  
2  2  3  .5
```

Comment: `df[['a','b']].pct_change(axis=1)`?

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Comment: @QuangHoang This however doesn't return a negative number for when the percent change goes down. This only shows absolute. How would I be able to get both the negative and positive percent change?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138777/4238408) in that question.